# finding an annihilator of ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ as follows

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Here's the complete problem.

Let $I$ be an ideal of the commutative ring $R$. Define the **annihilator** of $I$ to be the set
$Ann(I) = \lbrace r\in R \mid ra = 0 \ for \ all \ a \in I \rbrace$.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ be a ring and $I=\lbrace \overline{n} \mid n \ is \ even \rbrace$. Prove that $I$ is ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Find $Ann(I)$.

**My answer:**

Since $\overline{0} \in I, I \neq \emptyset$. Let $s,t \in I$. That is,
$s = \overline{n_1}$ and $t = \overline{n_2}$, for some even integers $n_1,n_2$. Then, $s-t = \overline{n_1} - \overline{n_2} = \overline{n_1-n_2} \in I$.
Now, for $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$, we have $rs = r\overline{n_1} \in I$ and $sr = \overline{n_1}r \in I$
since the result of the product of an arbitrary integer with an even integer is always even. Hence, $I$ is ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.
Next, we must find some elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, say $r$, such that for all $a \in I, ra = 0$. I found that $Ann(I) = \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{10} \rbrace$, since for all $n \in I$ and $m\in Ann(I), mn = \overline{0}$.

Is my answer above overall corect?
Please correct me if I wrong. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Looks good, although you should also show that for $m\ne0,10$ there exist $n$ in the ideal such that $mn\ne0$.

Comment: emmm, any idea to show it?

Comment: Just take $n=2$.

Comment: for example, take $m=5$ and $n=2$ and then $mn\ne 0$ ?

Comment: showing just with example is allowed ?

Comment: The point is, not just $m=5$, but any $m$ other than $0,10$, you get $2m\ne0$. To put it the other way around, show $2m=0$ implies $m$ is $0$ or $10$.

Comment: Oh, okay got it. Thanks sir!

Comment: Like this? : Suppose there are exist $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{20}, m \ne \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{10} \rbrace$ and exist $n \in I$, such that $mn = \overline{0}$. Let's take $n=2$. Then, $2m = \overline{0}$ which implies that $m= \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{10} \rbrace$. Contradiction. Hence, the only $m$ are $m = \lbrace \overline{0}, \overline{10} \rbrace$. Like this Sir ?

Comment: All you have to do is show that if $2m=0$ then $m\in\{0,10\}$ – but you do have to show this, you can't just assert it. Once you have shown it, you have shown that $0,10$ are the only possible elements of the annihilator.

Comment: And so, is above correct Sir ?

Comment: What's above is a mess. You can't say "suppose there exists $n\in I$ ..." and then say "let's take $n=2$". And, to reiterate, you have to **show** that $2m=0$ implies $m$ is in $\{0,10\}$, you can't just **assert** it. And you don't mean $m=\{0,10\}$.

Comment: So, how to start the prove?

Comment: You can't prove that $2m=0$ implies $m$ in $\{0,10\}$?

Comment: I can ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I mean, how to start the prove, not to prove that $2m=0$ implies $m\in 0,10$.

Comment: Look, I'm not your private tutor. You're going to have to work through methods of setting out proofs. There are probably lots of examples in your study materials, and staff wherever you are studying who are paid to help you. Or hire a tutor.

Comment: Okay thanks ${}{}{}$

Comment: Take $n=2$. Then, $2m = 0 \Rightarrow m \in \{0,10\}$. Thus, the only possible $m\in \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ are $m\in \{0,10\}$. Like this ?